# Protobuf-net with Compact Framework 3.5

Tags: compact-framework, protobuf-net

I want to incorporate Protobuf-net into my app to handle binary serialization.
My app is being written in Vs2008 for CF 3.5.  I am unsure Which is the best download to use?

protobuf-net r282.zip has a CF35 version
protobuf-net r480.zip doesnt have anything similar

I would like to use the latest (and greatest) version, but don't know which one to use.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hmmm... I thought I'd included CF in the last build. My apologies - it is a bit of a pain because it involves a different VM due to the VS2008 requirement. It has certainly been included in many of the recent builds (I distinctly remember having to fix a CF build issue recently) - I must have just omitted it by accident. I'm not at a PC now, but I can try a build later if it helps.

Comment: Closing too localized, as is very specific - but; noted and will act.